# c# switch on variable type

Tags: c#, types, type-conversion, bitconverter

Is there a cuter way to do this? 
Given a byte stream to convert it to the desired number type.

(Assume the calling code will be handling data types relevant to the number of bytes in the stream).

```
    public void GetValue(byte[] bytes, ref UInt16 value)
    {
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(bytes);
        value = BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, 0);
    }
    public void GetValue(byte[] bytes, ref UInt32 value)
    {
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(bytes);
        value = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 0);
    }
    public void GetValue(byte[] bytes, ref UInt64 value)
    {
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
            Array.Reverse(bytes);
        value = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0);
    }
    etc...
```

I imagine there's a better way, by switching on the type of value, for instance, rather than having replicated overloads.

Comment: I would *start* by making the methods return a value and getting rid of the `ref` parameter... then naming the methods `GetInt32` etc. Using a `ref` parameter just so you can overload the method feels pretty horrible to me.

Comment: Oh, and you might want to look at http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil which includes `EndianBitConverter`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you can extract the conditionality of the array reversal, and I wouldn't use overloads at all:

```
public ushort GetUInt16(byte[] bytes)
{
    ReverseIfLittleEndian(bytes);
    return BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes, 0);
}

public uint GetUInt32(byte[] bytes)
{
    ReverseIfLittleEndian(bytes);
    return BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 0);
}

public ulong GetUInt64(byte[] bytes)
{
    ReverseIfLittleEndian(bytes);
    return BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0);
}

private static void ReverseIfLittleEndian(byte[] bytes)
{
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    {
        Array.Reverse(bytes);
    }
}
```

If you're really aiming to have a single method, I would avoid trying to get "cute" and stick with "simple and readable". Yes, you end up with several similar methods - but each is simple to understand, simple to call, and basically zero maintenance. Sounds good to me...